# Vuetify responsive grid cloumns based on breakpoint

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I want the columns to be responsive and act according to breakpoints size change:

[image: lg and up]

[image: md]

[image: sm and down]

I really confused how to define this logic on Vuetify code!

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry if I'm late. Here's my take on your problem using `v-row` inside a `v-col` with no vertical paddings.

```html
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="12" md="6" class="py-0">
    <v-row :column="$vuetify.breakpoint.mdAndDown">
      <v-col cols="12" lg="6" style="border: 1px solid red;">1</v-col>
      <v-col cols="12" lg="6" style="border: 1px solid red;">2</v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-col>
  <v-col cols="12" md="6" style="border: 1px solid red;">3</v-col>
</v-row>
```

Here's a [working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-wilbur-5g3r8?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:11-335) and here's a sample output.
[image]